# Why would reversing the order on my training set in Scikit learn change the predictions?

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a training set in sci-kit learn that I'm using with the Perceptron algorithm. I flipped the training set's order, just to see what happened, and I'm surprised that I am seeing different results.

Do you know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Perceptron algorithm as implemented in scikit-learn is sensitive to data ordering by nature as it is a sequential algorithm with a `n_iter` hard stopping criterion. In particular it is recommended to shuffle the data to ensure that examples of different classes have equal likelihood to occur at the beginning and the end of the learning. The classical stopping criterion of the Perceptron algorithm (stability of the last epoch) is not implemented in scikit-learn. If you increase `n_iter` you will probably see less different outcomes .